# Alternatives of/Configuring AWS secrets manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

Currently, Our Security engineering team is not allowing to write in secrets manager but read is fine.

We have a common lambda role which is being used by other modules as well.

1. Is there any way to configure writing limited to only particular secrets ?
2. Alternatives to AWS secrets manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is there any way to configure writing limited to only particular secrets?

Yes. [This official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconnect/latest/ug/iam-policy-examples-asm-secrets.html#iam-policy-examples-asm-specific-secrets) shows how to grant read access to only specific secrets. You could do the same thing with write access.

> 2. Alternatives to AWS secrets manager.

[AWS SSM Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html)

Answer (score 1):

Strong recommendation for using Secrets Manager or SSM Parameter Store to store secrets, but there are also other, non-AWS alternatives like Hashicorp's Vault. It can be found from AWS Marketplace (https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-ngzq6n42psnxa) or downloaded from the vendor website (https://www.vaultproject.io/).

Don't forget to ask security team review and approval before using it in production environments. :-)